# Extend search to include other sites in SXA not showing result

Tags: content-search, sxa

I have Site1 and Site2 in same tenant and I want to see serach results from Site2 while staying in context of Site1. I have also added Site2 in "DatasourceSearchScope" Site1 -> Settings -> Search criteria to extend search according to SXA documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting with Sitecore support I got the answer:

The field which should be used in order to achieve the required behavior is the "Associated Content (if empty search results will be narrowed to the current site)" field.

So, the actual article should be updated as follows:

Go to /sitecore/content/TENANT_GROUP/TENANT/SITE/Settings and in the Search Criteria section, in the DatasourceSearchScope field, click the sites that you want to include in the search. If you leave this field empty, only the current site will be searched.

should say

Go to /sitecore/content/TENANT_GROUP/TENANT/SITE/Settings and in the Search Criteria section, in the 
Associated Content field, click the sites that you want to include in the search. If you leave this field empty, only the current site will be searched. 
changes

The actual change is only the used field: DatasourceSearchScope -> Associated Content.

Answer (score 1):

Like it's mentioned in the documentation first you have to configure additional search scope:

[image]

In general, this should be enough. Ensure that you see any results at all and don't forget about proper sites configuration. Add an asterisk to your main site (site where you want to run the search) Host Name field so that it will take all of the search service responses:

[image]

Comment: I have setup accordingly [https://www.screencast.com/t/JnZyk2sMKQ] but still can't see items from Site2 as I am searching from i.e local.site1/search but still showing result only related to site1. config settings [https://www.screencast.com/t/KRVKcpsdp] and binding settings as follows: [https://www.screencast.com/t/AcBityq4g5IV]

Comment: Host name have * as mentioned in above screen shots

Comment: Probably you've already done it but ensure that you have all of the items properly indexed.

Comment: I think items indexed properly because when I searched within the site it displayed the results.